# virt_to_bus() is deprecated in linux kernel module compilation

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Hi I have written a kernel module that do 2 MB kmalloc (for physical contiguous memory) and convert its virtual address to bus address using `virt_to_bus()` to sent it back to application.

I need bus address because I have to transfer it to another system running linux and connected to host system using pcie-link. Now another system would be able to initiate a DMA transfer using this bus address.

Problem is: `virt_to_bus()` is deprecated and results in warning, is there any other way around to translate this address to bus address?

Comment: Consider reading LDD Chapter 15 (Memory mapping and DMA), it's great.

Answer (score 6):

> is there any other way around to translate this address to bus address

Yes, use `virt_to_phys`. A quick trip in the kernel shows this for x86:

```
#define virt_to_bus virt_to_phys
#define bus_to_virt phys_to_virt
```

Their generic counterparts, defined in asm-generic/io.h simply cast to `unsigned long` / `void *` respectively.

---

Of course you know you can always just subtract `PAGE_OFFSET` for linear mapped memory to obtain the physical address.

#### EDIT

> I am using arm

In that case you're likely looking for `dma_map_single`.

```
static inline dma_addr_t dma_map_single(struct device *dev, void *cpu_addr,
    size_t size, enum dma_data_direction dir)
```

> The buffer has to be pre-allocated (e.g. using kmalloc()). DMA for it
>   is set up with dma_map_single().

---

I really have little experience with DMA but there's a lot of information out there pointing out that `dma_map*` should replace `virt_to_bus`.

Comment: HI,I am using arm, this warning is not there when using X86 PC. on other architectures bus address may be differ from physical address. I need bus address not the physical address because DMA devices works on bus addresses. can you suggest something about this ?

Comment: @flying-high What architecture are you using ?

Comment: Hi, I am using ARM cortex-A8, but my module must be generic, so that it can also run on X86 and other arch.